# PHP form image upload is working but text input does not store in database

Tags: php, mysql

I created a form where using PHP and MySQL .Here people can input text and upload image.My image upload part is working .Image is storing in database but text does no store in database

My codes are below :

index.php

```
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="username">
       <input type="text" name="report">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="image"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
    </form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

    if($check !== false){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        /*
         * Insert image data into database
         */

        //DB details
        $dbHost = 'localhost';
        $dbUsername = 'root';
        $dbPassword = 'root';
        $dbName = 'testreport';

        //Create connection and select DB
        $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

        // Check connection
        if($db->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
        }

       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['username']);
        $report = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['report']);
        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        //Insert image content into database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (username,report,image, created) VALUES ('$username','$report','$imgContent', '$dataTime')");
        if($insert){
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        }else{
            echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
        } 
    }else{
        echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try with $_POST instead of $_REQUEST $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); instead of $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['username']);

Comment: what is $link and where if come from.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be $_POST[''] because the form method was 'post'
so it will be :

```
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
   $report = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['report']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define link like this for mysqli_real_escape_string()

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","testreport");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$report = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['report']);
$dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

As you are using mysqli_real_escape_string you need to pass mysqli object in first parameter.
[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)